# SOQL query times out

Tags: soql, findduplicates

In our org, we have 60 million Account records many of which are duplicates.
We are trying to find all those duplicate records based on their golden Id(MDM). We are trying the below query in Batch and other tools but it times out anyway.

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) ID, R1_ACC_TXT_Id_Golden_record__c FROM ACCOUNT WHERE CreatedDate=Last_YEAR GROUP BY R1_ACC_TXT_Id_Golden_record__c HAVING COUNT(ID)>1 limit 1000
```

Is there a way to find out at least the count of duplicate records with their salesforce ID?We also have informatica ETL tool that we can make use of.

Regards,
Chetan

Comment: Can you batch iterate the "golden record" values and count Account duplicates for each of those in a more targeted query? You will run separate queries per golden record, or number of golden records, so instead of 1 query you will have n queries, each of which deals with just a "small" set of data rather than everything.

Comment: Can you extend the `where` clause to include additional indexed filters? You may also want to review an old but accepted [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22365/find-duplicate-records-based-on-multiple-fields) around this area too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run a [Duplicate Job](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_jobs_run_and_manage.htm&type=5), then you can easily export the [DuplicateRecordItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_duplicaterecorditem.htm) and/or [DuplicateRecordSet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_duplicaterecordset.htm) values to get all the duplicates (each set defines a group of duplicate items). Aside from exporting all the data and massaging offline, this is probably the most convenient way to do this.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, I have run the duplicate job by creating a matching rule on golden ID of records.I am assuming it will scan all the 60+ million records.

Comment: Is it possible to accomplish through any ETL tool to find the same say Mulesoft?

Comment: @Chetan The GROUP BY query is limited to 2,000 groups (so, 2,000 groups of records). This probably won't help you if you have a large number of duplicates. A System Administrator can run this query, but it will take a long time and will only return at most 2,000 groups. The Matching Rule will match all the records, though it will also take some time to scan the records, but it will successfully complete.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. So the result produced by this job is downloadable?

Comment: @Chetan Yes, you can use your favorite ETL tool to download the information

Comment: I googled but i don't see how i can use Mulesoft(since i am starting to learn it) to download them?Can you please be kind enough to direct me in right direction. I see we can also use the results in reports .

Comment: @Chetan In the query editor, you can use `select R1_ACC_TXT_Id_Golden_record__c from account where id in (select recordid from DuplicateRecordItem)` (or any other fields you'd like). You can query DuplicateRecordSet if you want the total number of duplicate groups (as in your original query).

Comment: Thanks mucho @sfdcfox.